# Plot Time on x axis but keeping the date sequence

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib, concatenation, read.csv

I have big data frame created in python as shown below. it has four columns. I am plotting Time on Xaxis, and A  and B on Yaxis. As time is in 24hour format so when a new day starts the time offcourse start back from 0:0 as can be seen in row 275. 
I want to plot Time on X axis with date sequence to follow so my data looks continous. Appreciate if anyone can help with a code. Thanks alot

```
Data Frame

       "Date"    "Time"       "A"       "B"
0    2017-07-31  14:52:55  -0.032374  -0.027602   
1    2017-07-31  14:54:55  -0.032313  -0.027549   
2    2017-07-31  14:56:56  -0.032256  -0.027405   
3    2017-07-31  14:58:55  -0.032316  -0.027591   
4    2017-07-31  15:00:55  -0.032418  -0.027704   
5    2017-07-31  15:02:57  -0.032416  -0.027550   
6    2017-07-31  15:04:56  -0.032415  -0.027666
..          ...       ...        ...        ...
275  2017-08-01  00:00:56  -0.031791  -0.027092   
276  2017-08-01  00:02:56  -0.031779  -0.027155   
277  2017-08-01  00:04:56  -0.031901  -0.027234   
278  2017-08-01  00:06:55  -0.031903  -0.027206
..          ...       ...        ...        ... 
360  2017-01-08  02:50:55  -0.032319  -0.027562
```

I have attached my plot. It can be seen that the data starting on the new date has shift to the left side of the plot which i dont want. I want it to continue from the last time of the previous day.

[image]

Comment: There are lots of example on the pandas website about plotting time/date series. Have you tried following any of their examples?

Comment: Yes i did. But i didnt find specific to my case thats why i asked here. @tom

Comment: You need to make a new column that is a datetime, and plot that.

Comment: Yes, i have done that using this `dates = pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(1),dayfirst=True)`
    `df.insert(0, 'Datetime', dates)` the only thing is, on x axis, it is ploting M:D - HH. I need to include mintutes as well. Any idea how can i do that. Thanks @cphlewis